# str_ireplace not working with German characters

Tags: php, string-formatting

I am using the following function to search for words and color them inside a text. It works perfectly except for German characters (ä, ë, ß, etc). I already tried to encode to utf, decode, checked my meta tags and everything else like that but the problem is not the encoding as they show correctly on the site, they're just not "colored" by this function:

```
function highlight($keyword, $input, $linktext, $color){
    $text = $input;
        $word = $keyword;
        $text = str_ireplace(" ".$word, ' <span id="">' . $word . '</span>', $text);

        $iteration = 1;
        while (true) {
          $text = preg_replace('/<span.id="">' . $word . '<\/span>/imsxU', '<span style="background:'.$color.'" class="keyword" id="link' . 
                               $iteration . "\" onclick=\"setLink2('$keyword','$linktext',$iteration)\">" . $word . '</span>', $text, 1, $count);
          if (!$count) {
            break;
          }
          $y++;
          $iteration++;
        }

        return $text;

}
```

Any idea of how can I achieve this? I also tried to replace them but the German words should apear as they are on the text so that's a no go =/

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as str_ functions in PHP do not support UTF, you have to use the mb_ extension. In your case, replace str_ireplace with [mb_eregi_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php)

Comment: changing that would make me change:
    str_ireplace(" ".$word, ' <span id="">' . $word . '</span>', $text);
 to
    mb_eregi_replace($text, ' <span id="">' . $word . '</span>'," ".$word); 
right? Because that won't show me anything once the site loads. Maybe I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Enable error reporting to see what the actual error is, it may be you don't have the multibyte extension installed.

Comment: @LuisArmando try showing all the errors, maybe you're missing something. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`